# Does 'this friday' take に

Tags: grammar, particle-に, time

I'm happy that the following is correct:

> 金曜日にケーキを食べる.
>
> I will eat cake on Friday.

But what about this:

> 今週の金曜日にケーキを食べる
>
> I will eat cake (on) this Friday

In English putting "on" in the latter sentence is wrong.　Should I use に in this case? Thanks.

Comment: Hint:  Do not try to translate particles to exact words or situations in English.

Comment: This is especially true for stating times, as English has very inconsistent rules when it comes to prepositions (this Friday, on Friday, at 5 pm, in December, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are making a mistake lots of people make – you are trying to think about what your sentence will look like in English. You might do this with most European languages, but you definitively can't do this with Asian languages.

So as you said, your first sentence is correct:

> 金曜日にケーキを食べる.

Basically, all you did in your second sentence was indicate that you are talking about this Friday (the Friday of this current week). This is all about it, your sentence is, of course, correct:

> 今週の金曜日にケーキを食べる

Japanese is like lego, you basically you do: (something + particle)^n + verb.
This is not really true of course since you can have several verbs in a sentence, but basically this is like lego so:

> 金曜日に => 今週の金曜日に
>   ケーキを
>   食べる

Since you kept your sentence structure, you shouldn't ask yourself if your sentence is still correct or not. Also, these sentences are also correct:

> ケーキを今週の金曜日に食べる
>   ケーキを金曜日に食べる

I just swapped 2 lego, that's all, so my grammar is still correct.